# Is there a way to dynamically create a TBSelect2 dropdown widget from Yii?

Tags: javascript, php, yii, drop-down-menu

The TBSelect2 Dropdown menu is an awesome widget from Yii. Provides a search in the dropdown menu and also looks really good!

I'm creating a basic messaging system for a project I'm working on. When I initially load the page, I retrieve the active convos from the controller and set them up in my view, each with a TBSelect2 dropdown menu like so:

```
$this->widget(
     'TbSelect2',
     array(
          'name' => $meet_me_dropdown_id,
          'data' => array('' => '') + $locations,
          'options' => array(
                            'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Meet me @'),
                            'minimumResultsForSearch' => 9,
          ),
          'htmlOptions' => array(
                                'class' => 'send_message_dropdown',
                                'data-friend-agreement-id' => $friend_agreement_id
          )
     )
);
```

Now, the problem is when I am on the page and would like to add a new convo, I cannot dynamically create a TBSelect2 widget by javascript.

Is there a way that I can create it without having to reload the page?

I am using PHP and Javascript in the Yii Framework.

Comment: Try to initialize your select2 by jQuery after settling convo up in view. There is no need to use `$this->widget(...)`. Look here https://select2.github.io/